# How to add a new row to pandas dataframe with non-unique multi-index

Tags: pandas, multi-index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4*3).reshape(4,3), index=[['a','a','b','b'],[1,2,1,2]], columns=list('xyz'))
```

where df looks like:

[image]

Now I add a new row by:

```
df.loc['new',:]=[0,0,0]
```

Then df becomes:

[image]

Now I want to do the same but with a different df that has non-unique multi-index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4*3).reshape(4,3), index=[['a','a','b','b'],[1,1,2,2]], columns=list('xyz'))
```

,which looks like:

[image]

and call

```
df.loc['new',:]=[0,0,0]
```

The result is "Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

How could I achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `append` or `concat` with helper `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0]], 
                   columns=df.columns, 
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['new'], ['']]))
df2 = df.append(df1)

df2 = pd.concat([df, df1])
print (df2)
       x   y   z
a   1  0   1   2
    1  3   4   5
b   2  6   7   8
    2  9  10  11
new    0   0   0
```

Comment: thank you so much for great help. I will click on the accept button in 10 minutes (system default) :)